# Explicitly tasking Keychain Access to sync

Tags: icloud, keychain

It is not clear to me if Keychain Access syncs up with peer devices on the network or if the username/password data is stored in iCloud (yikes, vulnerability).

From macOS Catalina or newer, is there a GUI method or terminal command (preferable) to prompt Keychain Access to sync up with a source?

Guidance from Apple forums is iffy / spotty: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250193336 in the sense recommendation is to toggle iCloud Keychain.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As you have enabled (per your screenshot) iCloud sync for Keychain - the Keychain is synced with iCloud. It's not a vulnerability in itself.

Keychains are never synced peer-to-peer on the network.

There's no command line tool to choose to sync the Keychain with a peer on your local network, as there's no peer-to-peer sync at all.

Note that Keychain Sync occurring via iCloud does not mean that the Keychain data is simply stored in iCloud Drive. That is not how this works.

Instead the iCloud Keychain uses a completely separate manner of synchronisation that builds on a ["circle of trust"](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec0a319b35f/1/web/1) model. This means that unless you give Apple your Keychain credentials, [they cannot read](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/secdeb202947/1/web/1) the contents of the Keychain - even when synced with iCloud. This is [also true](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/security/sec3e341e75d/1/web/1) for when you need to do a full Keychain recovery.

In regards to Apple Forums - please be aware that you're communicating with Apple employees, but other users like yourself. However, the link you have shown does not as such recommend users to enable Keychain Syncing. The original question states that the user has already enabled Keychain Syncing, but believes it not to be working - where another user recommends turning syncing off and back on again.